# Помогите разобраться (Изменения в API разработчика Google Play)

Tags: java, android

Начиная с 1 декабря 2019 года версии 1 и 2 API Google Play для разработчиков больше не будут доступны, поэтому вам необходимо обновить версию 3 до этой даты.

Вот статья 
https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2019/03/changes-to-google-play-developer-api.html

Что конкретно они хотят что нужно обновить??

Вот список моих библиотек ?

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "dima113xxx.idz_math"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 2
        versionName "2"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.billingclient:billing:1.2'
}
```

---

```
  // Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

    buildscript {
        repositories {
            google()
            jcenter()

        }
        dependencies {
            classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.1'

            // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
            // in the individual module build.gradle files
        }
    }

    allprojects {
        repositories {
            google()
            jcenter()

        }
    }

    task clean(type: Delete) {
        delete rootProject.buildDir
    }
```

Comment: покажите весь гредл файл

Comment: Вам нужно зайти в PlayConsole и посмотреть есть ли там предупреждения. Если есть действуйте.

Comment: Да есть , я   собственно из них на эту статью попал . Что значит действуйте? Что обновлять та ?

Comment: @Роман Текст предупреждения в студию. Обновлять com.android.billingclient:billing:1.2 до 'com.android.billingclient:billing:2.0.3', но это еще не все, нужно переделывать код, потому что покупки нужно теперь подтверждать. Удачи в чтении инструкций.